# Changing cmake default compiler

Tags: cmake

Cmake uses GNU `c++` when `CXX` environment variable is not defined and `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=...` is not passed to cmake.

How do I change default (to `clang++`)?

Comment: I recommend using toolchain files instead, possibly combined with cmake presets. This allows you to choose between different compilers and the only thing you need to specify is one the path to the toolchain file or the preset name. In case you're using presets, you could even specify predetermined directories to use as build directories as well as cache variables to set when using the preset...

Answer (score 0):

> Cmake uses GNU c++ when CXX environment variable is not defined [..]
>
> How do I change default (to clang++)?

Export `CXX=clang++` in your environment.

Comment: That's my question: is there a way to change default compiler when `CXX` is not defined and `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is not used

Comment: Yes, define `CXX`. It is not defined. So define it. And export. CXX exactly exists so that you can set a default c++ compiler. It's what it is for. I do not understand. `Cmake uses GNU c++` You can create an executable named `c++` that will run clang and add it to PATH.